# Laravel JOIN replace if not NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to know if it's possible to create a join in laravel/sql which only replaces the values if they are not null.

I'm trying to create a "changes" table. If changes are made to an user it gets saved to the changes table. If a person then wants to select all users he can see the users and if they exist in the changes table he sees the changes in the result.

Example:
I have an users table with the field: name and age.
An person changes the age and a new row comes in the changes table with the name field on NULL and the age to the new age.

Then i select the users table and see the old name (because it's NULL in the changes table) and the new age (also because its in the changes table)

Tried it with a join but that doesn't do the trick:

```
$data = DB::table('changes') 
        ->join('users', 'changes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include your code in the question if you have tried something.

Comment: The answer is yes, this is possible. If you could include an example of the data and query results you are looking for, this would be helpful.

Comment: if you have users with null changes then why dont you do DB::table('users')->('changes') ?

Comment: @Rodrane huh what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think an inner join should do the trick , here is an idea:

you query your changes table, group by user_id, select the one with most recent date, and then inner join with your users table ... but I don't think you do that with Eloquent, RAW sql maybe the thing you want ...

Comment: "group by the user_id" but the name of the column: "user_id" is not the same as from the users: "id"